# Ignore class members based on version?

Tags: c#

I'm working with an application which change their database models quite often and we have multiple versions of the application installed around in my company at the same time.

This has made a "challenge" for my homemade app, since I am not sure how to handle the models for all the different versions. Right now, I have 4 different library dlls including the different models and you have to manually change the dll according to the version you're working with, all compiled with the same name, eg. "MovieLib.dll".

Is there some sort of attribute I can set or other solutions, so I dont need to have tons of duplicate code?

Example

```
\\MovieDbApp version 1.0
public class Movie 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}

\\MovieDbApp version 1.1
public class Movie 
{
    public int MovieId{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}

\\MovieDbApp version 1.2
public class Movie 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}

\\MovieDbApp version 1.3
public class Movie 
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There are squillions of ways you could solve this problem. It might be best to describe a bit more about the libraries and infrastructure you are using. E.g. are you using an ORM? An IOC container? Are you using .NET Core or Framework?

Comment: I would use only one class containing all the properties available in all the versions and keep the information of which properties are available in which database version as a separate information. This meta-information allows you hide or show controls in the UI accordingly. An ORM can map a property (like `Id`) to different column names at initialization (`Id` or `MovieId`).